# Habilitar un Combobox con otro Combobox

Tags: php, combobox

Tengo en mi pagina un formulario para agregar un establecimiento y dentro tengo 3 combobox, las opciones de los 3 son SI y NO, el primer Combobox es para preguntar si requiere pago, el segundo es Retribución y el tercero es Retribución no Pecuniaria, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que el segundo y tercer combobox estén siempre deshabilitados y solo se habiliten si en el primer combobox se elija la opcion SI.

Mis combobox son los siguientes:

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pago"><i class="fas fa-school"></i> Requiere Pago</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="pago">
            <option value="0" selected>-- SELECCIONE --</option>
            <?php foreach($pagos as $f):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $f->id; ?>"><?php echo $f->nombre_pago; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pecuniaria"><i class="fas fa-school"></i> Requiere Retribución 
            Pecuniaria</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="pecuniaria" disabled> 
            <option value="0" selected>-- SELECCIONE --</option>
            <?php foreach($pagos as $f):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $f->id; ?>"><?php echo $f->nombre_pago; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="no_pecuniaria"><i class="fas fa-school"></i> Requiere Retribución no 
             Pecuniaria</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="no_pecuniaria">
            <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
            <?php foreach($pagos as $f):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $f->id; ?>"><?php echo $f->nombre_pago; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            </div>
```

Los OPTION de los combobox los lleno desde una consulta a la BD, esto funciona bien.

Y estoy trabajando con un script que encontre pero no me funciona.

```
<script>
$("#pago").change(function() {
  if($("#pago").val() !== "0"){
    $('#pecuniaria').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else
  {
    $('#pecuniaria').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Si son para seleccionar entre Si y No, es mas apropiado usar casillas de selección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puedes basar en el índice seleccionado, pasándolo directamente a la función del evento:

```js
function cambio(i){
    ["pecuniaria","no_pecuniaria"].forEach(
        function(name){
            select = document.getElementsByName(name)[0];
            if( i != 1 )
                select.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
            else
                select.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    );    
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pago">
        <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
        Requiere Pago
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="pago" onChange="cambio(this.selectedIndex)">
        <option value="0" selected>
            -- SELECCIONE --
        </option>
        <option value="s">SI</option>
        <option value="n">NO</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pecuniaria">
        <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
        Requiere Retribución Pecuniaria
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="pecuniaria" disabled> 
        <option value="0" selected>
            -- SELECCIONE --
        </option>
        <option value="s">SI</option>
        <option value="n">NO</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="no_pecuniaria">
        <i class="fas fa-school"></i> 
        Requiere Retribución no Pecuniaria
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="no_pecuniaria" disabled>
        <option value="">
            -- SELECCIONE --
        </option>
        <option value="s">SI</option>
        <option value="n">NO</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono pero solo hay algo que me gustaria corregir, al seleccionar NO en requiere pago, tambien deberian desactivarse los otros 2 combobox

Comment: @Jeison: Sólo cambia la condición en el `if()`. Respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
$('select[name="pago"]').change(function() {

    let selectOption = $( 'select[name="pago"] option:selected' ).val();

    if ( selectOption == 'NO' ) {
        $('select[name="no_pecuniaria"]').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    } else {
        $('select[name="no_pecuniaria"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

});
```

Lo que hago es obtener el valor de la opción seleccionada con `let selectOption = $( 'select[name="pago"] option:selected' ).val();` y lo guardo en la variable `selectOption` luego simplemente verifico su valor, si es igual a NO entonces agrego el atributo disabled, en caso de no ser así elimino ese atributo.

la función se activo usando .change, es decir, cuando el valor cambia y seleccionado el select basado en un name, también puedes usar una clase o un ID.

Como el valor por defecto asumo es NO recomendaría agregar el atributo disabled en el html por defecto para luego hacer la verificación con js

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero probé tu código pero aun así no hace nada, consulta, en los combobox hay algo mas que hacer??

Comment: No parece haber error, intenta hacer un console.log( selectOption  ); dentro de la función .change para ver que te devuelve la variable